# Issues with Listview in a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments, adapter

I have a `ListView` in a `ListFragment` and in the code I wrote a code that says when an item of listview is clicked, open another activity.
The problem is when I click on an item, nothing happens!

This code works fine in an Activity, but not in a Fragment.

Code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String pid = ((TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                .toString();
        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new    Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                EditProductActivity.class);
        // sending pid to next activity
        in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivity(in);
    }
});
```

I replaced this code :

```
ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

with :

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Because it was giving me

```
content view not yet created
```

in logcat.

All the code:

```
package rappage.rapfarsi.media.appteam;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class tab1 extends ListFragment {

    static final String url_all_products = "http://aliak.xzn.ir/rap/get_all_products.php";
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // JSON Node names


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);




        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);




        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                .toString();
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivity(in);



                }
                });




        return v;

    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {





        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            Main.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            getActivity(), productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                    });

        }






    }



}
```

I hope you can help me....thanks

Comment: I'm not done with my code review, but you should avoid using the Application Context except you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @rekire i have edit second, i posted wrong one, plz if it possible take look at it!

Answer (score 0):

Extending from ListFragment you only have to redefine this method:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 //Handle click event
}
```

Instead of getting the list and setting its `onItemClickListener`

Comment: umm nope i get error! can u please write it for me with my code, i mean try editing my code , bcz this app is very imp for me to get finished

Comment: I afraid I shouldn't. We are here for helping, not coding. We can help you if you can send us your errors and excepcions

Comment: first thing thanks for everything! and second i know i didnt want u to code for me i just asked u if its possible edit my code that given with the code u gave me ! and error , what error? when i click nothing shows in logcat ! items are like deads nothing happens but exacylty this code works fine in and activity , but for some reason i have to use it in fragmentlist.... i hope u can help

Comment: Try replacing your first line in your onCreateView forma this one : View rootView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);